# Can Find() be called multipe times on a MongoCollection?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to update a property on each object within an array of objects with the value of a property on another object (MyObject). I am unclear if calling:

my_objects_collection = m_database.GetCollection(MY_OBJECTS_COLLECTION_NAME);

has any performance implications, so I tried calling it only once and executing a new Find command against it (with a modified filter for each iteration) within a For... Loop, see below:

```
            MyObject my_object = null;
            IMongoCollection<MyObject> my_objects_collection = null;

            if (objects != null)
            {
               my_objects_collection = m_database.GetCollection<MyObject>(MY_OBJECTS_COLLECTION_NAME);

                for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
                {
                    Expression<Func<MyObject, bool>> filter = x => (x.ID == objects[i].ID) && (x.LanguageCode == language_code);

                    my_object = await my_objects_collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

                    if (my_object != null)
                    { objects[i].DisplayName = my_object.Name; }
                }
            }
```

**However, the code above throws the following exception:**

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: collection

at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.Ensure.IsNotNull[T](T value, String paramName)
at MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollectionExtensions.Find[TDocument](IMongoCollection`1 collection, Expression`1 filter, FindOptions options)

If I move the my_objects_collection assignment inside the for loop, so that it is called for each iteration, the code works without throwing any exceptions.

Therefore my question is, **what happens to the MongoCollection reference (my_objects_collection) after the Find (or any other operation) is executed against it?**

I would really appreciated if anyone could provide some insight into this. I could move on since my application is working, but I really want to know why it throws an exception indicating that the collection is null for my own understanding.

Thank you in advance,

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of your exception, you do not need to perform a find for each individual record you retrieve, you could achieve this using the $in operator.

You could then loop the resultset and perform your update on each document. This is far more efficient as you are performing a single operation against the database to return your records, and then one for each update. Instead of one for each retrieval and one for each update.

See

```
Builders<MyObject>.Filter.In
```

Also if you want to match elements in an embedded array you could use

```
Builders<MyObject>.Filter.ElemMatch
```

A quick (untested) example

```
if (objects != null)
{
    var my_objects_collection = m_database.GetCollection<MyObject>(MY_OBJECTS_COLLECTION_NAME);

    var filterBuilder = Builders<MyObject>.Filter;

    var inFilter = filterBuilder.In(x => x.ID, objects.Select(x => x.ID));
    var andFilter = filterBuilder.And(
        inFilter, 
        filterBuilder.Eq(x => x.LanguageCode, language_code)
    );

    var results = await my_objects_collection.Find(andFilter).ToListAsync();

    foreach(var result in results)
    {
        //result is going to the a database object returns which matched your filter
    } 
}
```